# Cannot run Excel macro from VBScript

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have created a VBScript script that launches Excel and runs a specific macro in that workbook. It has worked successfully for many people for several months, but now, one of them has just moved to a new Microsoft Surface and he finds that the script does not work; receiving an error that a macro is disabled or unavailable. The script and the macro it calls still work perfectly well on his old laptop.

I did some research and confirmed what I had previously experienced: that launching an Excel workbook and running a macro in it does not ask the user to "Enable Content" -- and I guess that makes sense because if you have authority to run the VBScript then it is reasonable to assume that you also have authority to run the macro.

The problem here is that something in Excel seems to now be insisting that explicit approval needs to be given, and I don't see how to do that.

It is probably some setting in the Trust Center, but I have tried setting macros to always be enabled and that doesn't work either. I find the Trust Center all rather confusing and nothing seems to be an obvious candidate to fix this, and I don't want to experiment too much and ruin any important security settings.

Here's a snippet of my code; it seems to be failing on the "xlApp.Run" line:

```
Dim xlApp, xlWB

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWB = xlApp.WorkBooks.Open("C:\MIS\MIS.xlsm", , True)

xlApp.Run "'MIS.xlsm'!Launch"
xlWB.Close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Does anyone have any ideas, please?

EDIT: Perhaps I should have said: the VB Script is executing from inside a .hta file, but I wouldn't have thought that would make any difference in this case.

The error is not coming from Excel, so there is no opportunity to click on "Enable content" etc. -- it is coming from HTA/VBScript. VBS displays the error as a dialog box saying "An error has occurred in the script on this page", gives the line number of the xlApp.Run line, and says:

```
Cannot run the macro "'MIS.xlsm'!Launch". The macro may not  
be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
```

It also says that "Code" is 0 and provides the URL of the .hta file.

But the macro *is* available, and works for all other users, but not for this one on his MS Surface machine.

I guess the next thing for me to try is to create a minimal "proper" VBS script and see whether he has the same problem with that, but he doesn't respond to my questions very quickly!

EDIT 2: I have also tried changing the security settings in my Excel to try to replicate the problem but have so far failed -- the macro always runs for me!

EDIT 3: @Lankymart has found a solution in a previous question (that I didn't find, sorry) at [VBS that triggers a macro via HTA (Cannot run the macro)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422687/vbs-that-triggers-a-macro-via-hta-cannot-run-the-macro). I will change my HTA code accordingly, but it turns out that the user was lying -- he had previously been instructed to access the script via RDP, but on his new Surface he was using a direct mapped drive instead. Now that he is using RDP it works fine, so his Surface Excel environment is different from the RDP Excel environment. I hate it when people write "I've solved it!" on StackOverflow with no real answer but I'm afraid that's what is going to have to happen here -- I am able to interact with this user perhaps once a week if I am lucky, so there is no chance of a dialogue really.

How do I close this question as SOLVED?

Comment: I believe you need to use `xlApp.Application.Run`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad but `xlApp` _is_ an `Application` object, isn't it?

Comment: So, what's the current behavior? Does it ask the user to "Enable Content" or not? Maybe check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51888338/4934172) will help?

Comment: Can the user just open the workbook directly and run the macro manually?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed: Edited to show current behaviour. Thanks for your suggestion -- I will try modifying my script to the Low setting -- but that means leaving it at Low for the duration of the macro's execution -- and since that involves extensive user interaction it could be some time.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Normally, yes, but my client has asked that this should not look like Excel; they double-click on the .hta file and it then opens Excel invisibly except for a userform, with which the user then interacts, sometimes for several hours. My client wants this to look like a "proper" application, and not "something written in Excel".

Comment: @LewisKirby If I understand your situation correctly and if it's about macro security, you just have to change it until the Excel file is open. Once, the file is open, any change to the security level would only affect the next file(s) to be opened.

Comment: Does the macro have to be within the Excel workbook? If you're already using an HTA with VBScript, I would think it quite natural to port the userform and its interactions to the HTA.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed: Are suggesting I set it to Low just before the Open statement and then ByUI just after? If so, won't that mean that the .Run won't work? If you mean that I should set it to ByUI just after the .Run statement, then there is still the problem because the macro could take hours to return from -- the macro opens a userform with which the user interacts and they can take their time doing that.  Further, I don't understand why the macro works for everyone apart from this one person.

Comment: No... I meant just verify what happens when you run the Excel macro directly. You may get a more meaningful error message. Dose the Excel macro do anything that actually requires Excel?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: Gotcha, right. I'll ask him to try that the next time he is in touch, thanks, but the answer to your question is I don't know. All I know is that it works for him on his Desktop PC, but not on his Surface. And yes, it uses a lot of Excel once we get into the macro.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: Good thought, but it uses a lot of Excel behind the scenes and it would be several months of work to port it to HTA. I would rather simply tell him not to use his Surface!

Comment: @LewisKirby Even if it uses a lot of Excel, you could still manipulate the Excel application and its objects in the background, through a variable pointing to a hidden Excel application. The only thing you'd need to replace with the HTA is the UserForm and its code.

Comment: @ZevSpitz: Thanks for the suggestion, but when you say "manipulate the Excel application", don't you mean "run Excel macros"?  I would have thought that I would suffer from the same problem. The 'Launch' macro opens a userform that serves as the launch pad for the user interface that can open other userforms, update worksheets, etc, so I would have thought that if I have to put one macro into HTA then surely I would have put them all in there? Nevertheless, I'll put that on my list of things to consider, thanks.

Comment: HTA adds the complexity and might be the root of the problem. The simpler you make the solution, the less can go wrong and the easier it is to troubleshoot. Telling your user not to use new technology (surface pro) because your old technology (hta, vbscript, VBA) won't work on it is not really a forward thinking solution. At least get the actual error from Excel, not VBScript, and make a determination there

Comment: @Lankymart: Thank you for this -- yes, it's the same. I cannot tell whether this will fix the problem because the user has just got back to me and says it's working now that he is going in via RDP like he was supposed to! I'll alter my HTA just in case, but thank you.

Comment: How do I now mark this question as SOLVED please?

Comment: It needs an answer to be marked as solved. Can you create an answer that explains how it was solved (RDP) then you can accept it.

Comment: I didn't want to get into a conversation here, but "adding an answer" isn't an option here, perhaps because it is my question?. Or perhaps because it has been marked as Duplicate?